# Is there function in Oracle SQL which returns most recent record for every key?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, greatest-n-per-group

Oracle DB (PL/SQL).
I have two tables 'addresses' and 'characteristics'.

addresses

```
key         address
---         ---
1           101 Abbey road
2           16000 Calif st.
3           34 super way
4           some addr
5           That way
```

characteristics

```
key         char_name       value           birth_date
---         ---             ---             ---
3           name            Paul            01.01.1950
3           wife_name       Anna            01.01.1960
1           name            John            01.01.1950
3           kid_name        Eliza           02.02.1983
3           kid_name        Emma            03.03.1975
1           wife_name       Isabella        01.01.1948
1           kid_name        Lucas           08.08.1976
2           name            Liam            04.04.1980
2           kid_name        Dylan           09.09.2000
2           kid_name        Andrew          10.10.2002
2           kid_name        Scarlett        12.12.1999
5           name            Harley          07.07.2001
5           wife_name       Kitty           03.03.2003
```

Need to see list of  addresses with (man's name of who lives there), wife's name (if there is wife), *last* kid's name (if there are kids):

```
1           101 Abbey road      John            Isabella    Lucas
2           16000 Calif st.     Liam            ''          Andrew
3           34 super way        Paul            Anna        Eliza
4           some addr           ''              ''          ''          
5           That way            Harley          Kitty       ''
```

Is there function that returns most recent record by passing there key record value?
If no, please suggest select operator.

Comment: The "most recent" is just MAX in your case; group children by key and take the MAX birth_date

Comment: You don't need a function for this

Comment: With any SQL question, it would be good if you post a test case, which includes, create statement, few insert statements for sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's query for your requested list:

```
select key, address,name, wife_name, youngest_kid
from addresses
left join (
  select * from (
    select key key_, char_name, value
    from characteristics c
    where char_name in ('name', 'wife_name')
    OR birth_date = (
      select max(birth_date)
      from characteristics
      where char_name= 'kid_name'
      and key = c.key
      )
    )
  pivot (max(value) for (char_name) in ( 
    'name' as name,
    'wife_name' as wife_name,
    'kid_name' as youngest_kid
    )
  )
)
on key=key_;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle 11g + versions:

```
with temp_table as (select a.key, 
                           a.address,
                           b.char_name, 
                           b.value, 
                           b.birth_date,
                           rank() over (partition by b.key, b.char_name order by b.birth_date desc) rn
                     from addresses a
                     left join characteristics b on b.key = a.key),
final_table as (select key,address, char_name, value from temp_table where rn = 1)
select * 
  from final_table
 pivot (min(value) as nname for char_name in ('name' as name, 'wife_name' as wife, 'kid_name' as kid))
 order by 1;
```

for Earlier as well as 11g + versions:

```
with temp_table as (select a.key, 
                           a.address,
                           b.char_name, 
                           b.value, 
                           b.birth_date,
                           rank() over (partition by b.key, b.char_name order by b.birth_date desc) rn
                 from addresses a
                 left join characteristics b on b.key = a.key),
final_table as (select key,address, char_name, value from temp_table where rn = 1)
select key, 
       address, 
       min(decode( char_name, 'name', value, null)) name,
       min(decode( char_name, 'wife_name', value, null)) wife_name,
       min(decode( char_name, 'kid_name', value, null)) kid_name
  from final_table
  group by key, address
  order by key;
```

Both give same output

```
| KEY |         ADDRESS | NAME_NNAME | WIFE_NNAME | KID_NNAME |
|-----|-----------------|------------|------------|-----------|
|   1 |  101 Abbey road |       John |   Isabella |     Lucas |
|   2 | 16000 Calif st. |       Liam |     (null) |    Andrew |
|   3 |    34 super way |       Paul |       Anna |     Eliza |
|   4 |       some addr |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
|   5 |        That way |     Harley |      Kitty |    (null) |
```